# Is this <ul><li> text alignment a bug in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Opening this simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vrm485x/2/) in Firefox renders differently than in Chrome and other browsers.

---

**CHROME**
[image: chrome screenshot]

---

**FIREFOX**
[image: firefox screenshot]

---

I have actually been trying to make it look like Firefox in other browsers, i.e the bullet position follows the alignment of the text. Note that i'd also want the next list items to be centered, i.e not aligned based on the bullet position of the first one, [see screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhXv6.png). Anyone know a way?

I have seen answers using `list-style-position: inside`, but can't live with the side effect of the difference in the gap between the bullet and the text.

```
<ul>
  <li style="text-align: center;">Hello I'm Centered</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the issue with using `list-style-position: inside`?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a pseudo element like `:before` instead to get the desired effect across all browsers. By setting the `margin-right` you can choose the spacing yourself too.

```
li{
  text-align:center;
  list-style:none;
}
li:before{
   content:'•';
   margin-right:7px
}
```

What's happening is that `list-style:none` hides the default bullet and by using `:before` you're able to add it back in as an inline pseudo element.

Comment: Please see thread with @DriveItLikeYouStoleIt for discussion regarding this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally browsers are rather free what exactly to do with the dot in lists. I can easily imagine situations, where Firefox’ solution results in a better rendering.

If the `<li>` makes trouble, move the text alignment one element farther down, i.e., add a helper element:

```
<ul>
<li><div style="text-align: center;">Hello I'm Centered</div></li>
</ul>
```

Disadvantage is, that you introduce an element solely for reasons of styling, but in my experience pragmatism beats purism in such an isolated case.

Comment: This has no effect in chrome?

Comment: This will have no change in chrome. The goal is to have all browsers look like FF.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I’ve read that the other way round. I think in this case @jleggio’s answer is possibly the best. The usual tricks with `display` don’t work, because then the `li` loses its bullet.